# Is is possible to cherry-pick the db connection (persistent) django will use on each request on a per client/session basis?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, connection-pooling

I'd like to be able to tell someone (django, *pgBouncer*, or whoever can provide me with this service) to always hand me the same connection to the database (PostgreSQL in this case) on a per client/session basis, instead of getting a random one each time (or creating a new one for that matter).

To my knowledge:

1. Django's *CONN_MAX_AGE* can control the lifetime of connections, so
   far so good. This will also have a positive impact on performance
   (no connection setup penalties).
2. Some pooling package (*pgBouncer* for example) can hold the connections and hand them to me as I need them. We're almost there.

The only bit I'm missing is the possibility to ask pgBouncer (or any other similar tool for that matter) to give me a **specific** db connection, instead of "one from the pool". This is important because I want to have control over the lifetime of the transaction. I want to be able to open a transaction, then send a series of commands, and then manually commit all the work, or roll everything back should something fail.

Many years ago, I've implemented something very similar to what I'm looking for now. It was a simple connection pool made in C which would hold as many connections to oracle as clients needed on one hand, while on the other it would give these clients the chance to recover these exact connections based on some ID, which could have been for example a PHP session ID. That way users could acquire a lock on some database object/row, and the lock would persist even after the apache process died. From that point on the session owner was in total control of that row until he decided it was time to commit it, or until the backend decided it was time to let the transaction go by idleness.